# Rails how to populate dropdown from DB. Herlp or ivar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

My rails app has a number of forms that use select tags. To date, to populate these selects I've been initialising an ivar(s).

But it is becoming bit of a maintenance issue. It's easy to remember to populate an ivar when you are in a `new` or `edit` action. It's the `create` and `update` actions that are more problematic. Those ivars required by the form only need to be populated when there is an validation (or error) issue with the model.

Considering that the ivars are not needed when responding to xml or json requests, I'm questioning is there a better way.

Is this a case where I should be using helpers within my _form partial? To date I've always considered database access within a helper to be a code smell - but now I'm not so sure.

Just in case my post isn't clear:

```ruby
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  # this is what i do now - but is there a better way
  unless @user.save
    load_form_required_ivars # here I'm unnecessarily 
                             # hitting the db for json/xml requests
  end

  respond_with(@user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible` to hold these values of the drop down you are populating. as you validate in the create and then pass their values back if there are validation issues.

I don't get the part about xml and json being different however, but this should work for that too.

Comment: So you would advocate adding attrs on the model to hold the collection values. I guess then the model is then moving away from a domain model per se towards a view model.

Comment: Re XML and json: if my user form includes a role membership drop down then I need to grab from the db a list of roles when responding to HTML. But if an update is being performed via ajax and there is a problem, my json response does not require I retrieve the list of all available roles. There is no drop down. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: You can add a constant too like `ROLES = ['admin', 'bugger', 'peasant']` so nothing hits the db until create, if i read you correctly. As for worrying about view vs domain vs..yagni... get the job done and refactor mate. The same medal is handed out for lame code as perfection.